# How to use Load and Store of atomic in golang

Tags: go, atomic

Here are the piece of code to test the mutual access of write and read of a struct B using atomic.Value, but I've got some error indicating invalid pointer access. So what should I do? And what is the idiomatic of doing this?

```
type A struct {
    numMap map[string]int
}

type B struct {
    numMap map[string]*A
}

var store atomic.Value

var chanA chan bool = make(chan bool, 100)
var chanB chan bool = make(chan bool, 100)

var b *B = &B{}

func fetchB() {
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        c := store.Load().(B)
        for k, v := range c.numMap {
            fmt.Println(k, v)
            for k2, v2 := range v.numMap {
                fmt.Println(k2, v2)
            }
        }
    }
    chanA <- true
}

func writeB() {
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        //b := store.Load().(B)
        a := new(A)
        a.numMap = make(map[string]int)
        a.numMap["AMap"] = i
        b.numMap = make(map[string]*A)
        b.numMap["str"] = a
        b.numMap["strA"] = a
        delete(b.numMap, "str")
        delete(b.numMap["strA"].numMap, "AMap")
        store.Store(b)
    }
    chanB <- true
}
func main() {
    store.Store(*b)
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go writeB()
        go fetchB()
    }
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        <-chanA
        <-chanB
    }
}
```

I'm sorry I've missed something in the first post of the question. If I comment b := store.Load().(B) the error raises, and it is gone if i leave it visible. So why would this happen?

the error I've got is something like this:

```
panic: sync/atomic: store of inconsistently typed value into Value

goroutine 5 [running]: sync/atomic.(*Value).Store(0x597310, 0x4b7f40, 0x597198)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/atomic/value.go:76 +0x1e9 main.writeB()
    /home/bzhang/devCode/common/src/go/src/audience_service/test.go:47 +0x2cc created by main.main
    /home/bzhang/devCode/common/src/go/src/audience_service/test.go:54 +0x71

goroutine 1 [chan receive]: main.main()
    /home/bzhang/devCode/common/src/go/src/audience_service/test.go:59 +0xf3

goroutine 6 [runnable]: main.fetchB()
    /home/bzhang/devCode/common/src/go/src/audience_service/test.go:23 created by main.main
    /home/bzhang/devCode/common/src/go/src/audience_service/test.go:55 +0x89

goroutine 7 [runnable]: main.writeB()
    /home/bzhang/devCode/common/src/go/src/audience_service/test.go:36 created by main.main
    /home/bzhang/devCode/common/src/go/src/audience_service/test.go:54 +0x71

goroutine 8 [runnable]: main.fetchB()
    /home/bzhang/devCode/common/src/go/src/audience_service/test.go:23 created by main.main
    /home/bzhang/devCode/common/src/go/src/audience_service/test.go:55 +0x89

goroutine 9 [runnable]: main.writeB()
    /home/bzhang/devCode/common/src/go/src/audience_service/test.go:36 created by main.main
    /home/bzhang/devCode/common/src/go/src/audience_service/test.go:54 +0x7
```

Comment: Which Go version are you using?

Comment: I'm using go version go1.5.3 linux/amd64

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you get when run the program?

Comment: The program access the maps concurrently. Run your application with the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html).

Comment: To expand on the previous comment, maps are not goroutine-safe. If you are doing concurrent access to a map and one or more goroutines might be changing it, you need to protect it with a mutex (or equivalent).

Comment: Worth noting that atomic doesn't really buy you much here.  Your `B` struct is can be stored atomically, but maps are reference types, which means the changes in `WriteB` are visible in `WriteA` as they are run.  This shouldn't cause pointer errors (deleting a key from a map doesn't delete what the actual object that was stored there), but it does rather invalidate what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @Ankur I've edited this question and the errors is there.

Comment: @Kaedys thanks. So if the map is a reference type, how can we explain the effect of the "b := store.Load().(B)"?

Comment: @张张彪 You're loading the structure which contains the map into the variable b.  The store still holds the value properly, and via the atomic Load and Store operations, the _structure_ storage and loads are atomic.  The structure, however, contains a reference, and that reference doesn't inherit the atomic storage and retrieval, because other processes can change the object being referenced, even if they can't change the structure itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you comment out `b := store.Load().(B)` the variable `b` used in the function is the global `b` which is of type `*B` and when you do `store.Store(b)` you get the error because you are trying to store `*B` type value in the store which has value of type `B`. That's why the error talks about inconsistent type. You can change `store.Store(b)` to `store.Store(*b)` and the code will work without error.